# How to train a classifier to detect vernacular from grammatical language?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

I'm using text classification to classify Arabic dialects, so far I have 4 dialects. However, now I want the classifier to detect the formal(standard or grammatical) language of those dialects which is called MSA(Modern Standard Arabic).

Should I use grammatical analysis? build a language model? or I do the same as I did with the dialects by collecting MSA tweets and then train them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can train a language model for each dialects of the language. Then, given a sentence find the (log) probability returned by each language model and assign it to the language model which returns the high score.

```
p* = argmax p_i p_i(sentence)
```

where `p_i` is the language model of the dialects i.

Language model is a probability distribution over sequences of words. Given a sentence, say of length `m`, it assigns a probability `P(w1, ... ,wm)` to the whole sequence. So the sentence will belong to the dialect whose `P_i(w)` is high, where `P_i` is the language model of dialect `i`.

Comment: 1) I only have one formal language A, and then there're many dialects of that language A. The problem I'm facing is that many vocabularies are being shared between the formal language A and it's dialects. 2) What do you mean by language model here? a model to predict the next word in a sentence? 3) I'm also confused about your post a bit, you didn't use dialects here.

Comment: Is that what is called calculating the perplexity?

Comment: Are you saying I should train a separate classifier for each dialect?

Comment: do you have any references for that? your answer is not clear to me